# Permalink in const_url

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, ghost-blog, hexo

In my `config file` I basically have `permalink: :inLink/:title/` which makes the following possible:

`https://example.com/hello/post-1` (= all good!)

So, `inLink = hello` in my markdown file.

Now I have this line also …
`const post_url = config.get('page_url').replace('%SLUG%', event.slug)+'#comment-'+event.id;`

And this renders:
`https://example.com/post-1`(= bad!)

So the `inLink permalink variable hello` is missing from this.

Question is now how/where to add the `inLink variable` here in this line…
`const post_url = config.get('page_url').replace('%SLUG%', event.slug)+'#comment-'+event.id;` ???

Comment: what does config.get('page_url') return for you ?

Comment: @SirPeople - the page URL but the "inLink" variable (in my example "hello") is NOT included somehow. I am also very surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Ghost docs it specifies `page_url` as

> Helper - Output the URL for a given page in a list (i.e. next page)
>   This helper is used in the pagination template required by the {{pagination}} helper to output the URL for the next, previous or a specific page. It expects a variable which contains the page number you want to output.
>
> The helper can also interpret the strings "next" and "prev", to display a next/previous link outside of the context of pagination.

I think you want url, possibly the absolute URL

Something like:
`"{{url absolute="true"}}"`

Comment: Exactly. I was considering if he already had that set up and not working for some reason